# GitHub Actions won't start jobs wit job output in if statement

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, pipeline

Good day to you, colleagues!

I set up a workflow in which I wanted to start jobs only when some checks finished with "true". But jobs don't start. I used answers in [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25455) and [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25669) as an example but it doesn't work.

```
name: testing-workflow
run-name: test-run

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
    
jobs:

  check_where_changed:
    name: Check files
    outputs:
      modified_workflow_dir: ${{ steps.check_files_again2.outputs.modified_workflow_dir }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Check Modified Files In Workflow Directory
        id: check_files_again2
        run: |
          echo "checking paths of modified files"
          git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD > files.txt
          while IFS= read -r file
          do
            echo $file
            if [[ $file != .github/workflows/* ]]; then
              echo "This modified file is not under the workflows dir."
              echo "modified_workflow_dir=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
              break
            else
              echo "File modified in workflows dir, setting up variables"
              echo "modified_workflow_dir=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            fi
          done < files.txt
          cat $GITHUB_OUTPUT


  workflow_test:
    name: Job For Testing Purposes
    if: needs.check_where_changed.outputs.modified_workflow_dir == 'true'
    needs: [ check_where_changed ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Test echo
        run: echo "Testing Message"
```

Tried to fix syntax in different ways as was advised in different forums, ended up with official documentation syntax. Tried to read $GITHUB_OUTPUT with cat in workflow - everything seems fine, but next jobs wont start.

Comment: Have you printed the value of `needs.check_where_changed.outputs.modified_workflow_dir` in the next job without `if` to verify whether it actually contains the value?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "checks are finished"? Your trigger for your workflow is for when you push code into the repository. Depending on when you want this to run, you are likely using the wrong trigger.

Comment: @Azeem hm, no. Will try.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti i meant checks in job that do checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo in `modified_worflow_dir` --> `modified_workflow_dir` (missing `k`)

so try:

```
      modified_workflow_dir: ${{ steps.check_files_again2.outputs.modified_workflow_dir }}
```

instead of:

```
      modified_workflow_dir: ${{ steps.check_files_again2.outputs.modified_worflow_dir }}
```